# How to set up a star-mail

Tags: mailcore2

I want to set the star-mail messages to the inbox, now I just can and cancel starred in the first success in the future, will not have any effect.
The following is the way I use：

```
add start 
  [imapSession storeFlagsOperationWithFolder:"INBOX"
    uids:[MCOIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:11]
    kind:MCOIMAPStoreFlagsRequestKindAdd
    flags:MCOMessageFlagFlagged];
  add remove
  [imapSession storeFlagsOperationWithFolder:"INBOX"
    uids:[MCOIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:11]
    MCOIMAPStoreFlagsRequestKindRemove
    flags:MCOMessageFlagFlagged];
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you are looking for? The expected results and what you actually get?

Comment: Thanks, I expect starred messages, that can add remove Flagged / Starred flag. however I use the following method to add remove Flagged / Starred flag, in other mail clients to view, the result is added remove Flagged / Starred flag ok, but just only once. After Operation again， added remove Flagged / Starred flag ，in other mail clients to view，without any effect. I expect the result set  starred messages that other mail client will synchronization.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: oh, I want to the INBOX message add starrder flag with imap. but,I don't know how to do it.